# Show where f(x,y)=min(|x|,|y|) is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is f(x,y)=min(|x|,|y|) differentiable at point (0,0) and find the partial derivatives at the origin if they exist.

Now

$f(x,y)$=\begin{cases} 
                 |x|, & |x|\leq |y| \\
     \
                 |y|, & |y|<|x|
                \end{cases}

$\frac{\partial{f(x,y)}}{\partial{x}}= \begin{cases} 
                 \frac{x}{|x|}, & |x|\leq |y| \\
     \
                 0, & otherwise
                \end{cases}$

Answer (score 3):

No, the function is not differentiable at the origin. For example look at the line passing through the origin $y = x$. Here we have $f(x,x) = |x|$ which is not differentiable at $0$.

Note that if you look at the line $x = 0$ then $f(0,y) = 0$ and likewise with the line $y = 0$, so the partial derivatives in the directions $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are 0.

However, given any other line through the origin we get $f(ax,bx) = min(a,b)|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$, so the directional derivative does not exist.

[image: Plot of $f(x,y)$]

Comment: The directionnal derivatives may exists in every direction while the function being not differentiable. I do not understand your last sentence.

Comment: The linear restrictions of the function are differentiable for this function if and only if the linear restrictions are in the coordinate directions.

Comment: So don't you think you should replace your last "partial derivative" by "directionnal derivative" ? Becauses as you mentionned, both partial derivatives exist here.

Comment: Great point! Updated.